# Snapshot SBS or Single DC server environments

Tags: windows-server-2008, vmware-esxi, windows-sbs, hyper-v-server-2012

I can't seem to find a clear answer on this.

Is it safe or not safe to snapshot (or in my case checkpoint under HV 2012) an SBS or single DC server environment?  I took over an account and am behind on patches by about a year and would LOVE to be able to create a snapshot before doing this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With a no-fooling, you seriously double-checked, please go check again, *single* DC forest, there's no AD replication, so there's few risks of restoring that single DC if everything goes bad. So, for that very specific purpose, taking a snapshot is not a terrible idea.

There are always risks of retaining snapshots longer than x, where 'x' is usually considered 1 day, but may be much shorter depending on IO volume. So don't do that; snapshots are *only* for instant rollback or temporary storage of backup data destined for other, permanent media. As soon as the target guest has been confirmed OK, delete/consolidate that snapshot.

You should *also* take a full backup using your normal method. A method that you have tested performing restores from, in case other things go pear-shaped. Because you have this method in place already, right?

Comment: Yes we an onsite appliance doing whole server replication but I just wanted to conform nothing is 'hurt' by creating the snapshot/checkpoint on SBS (or single DC environments).  I've read reports that this should never be done but I've read reports where some people it.  I understand USN rollback issues.  Just trying to keep my patching nights down to a minumum :)  Thanks!

Comment: and I would only use it should the server not boot after patches for example.

Comment: Well, as I said, there's two issues with snapshots. One is, restoration of a DC from a snapshot will put your AD in a world of hurt in a multi-DC environment, so don't - issue is NA for your scenario. The other is, snapshots can be horribly abused (for any server) and if not cleaned up, will hurt IO performance badly.

Comment: Thank you for the details response.  Non multi DC environment - Check.  Keep checkpoints/snaphots from aging - Check.  I should be good to go then.  Thanks!